# geo_point type for elasticSearch bulk

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulk, geopoints

**Hi all!**

I am trying to put geo_point data to elasticSearch using the bulk method in the corresponding python library.
So I defined and upload successfully next mapping scheme ( I checked that scheme is set correctly  in the Kibana UI):

```
 {'mappings': {
            'properties': {
                           'location': {'type': 'geo_point'}
                           }
        }
 }
```

Then I am trying to put data with next code (I read ES manual and read examples here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
data = [{"index": {"_index": "geo_index", "_type": "geo_type"}}, {"location": (41.12, -71.34)}]

elasetic_search_instance = Elasticsearch(....)
elasetic_search_instance.bulk(data)
```

but here I faced with the next error:
'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'mapper [location] cannot be changed from type [geo_point] to [float]'}

I tried also to put geo_point as `"location":{"lat": 41.12,"lon": -71.34 }` or as string `"location":"41.12,-71.34"` and i got an errors that input data is incorrect ( "none" and "string" type correspondingly instead of "to [float]" in the previous error message).

I see that I am wrong with input data format but cannot understand how to do it correctly.
Please advise how I should reformat the input data format.

Thank you in advance!

P.S> for all other data types this uploading script works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of inconsistencies there, esp w/ the data list. Here's a working script for your use case:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

es_instance = Elasticsearch()

es_instance.indices.create('geo_index',
                           ignore=400,
                           body={
                               'mappings': {
                                   'properties': {
                                       'location': {
                                           'type': 'geo_point'
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                           })

data = [
    {"location": (41.12, -71.34)}
]

actions = [
    {
        "_index": "geo_index",
        "_source": point
    } for point in data
]

success_count, errors = bulk(es_instance, actions)

print((success_count, errors))
```

Comment: thanks, your code works fine, 
will check my code once more